# How can you continue to work with an undecided client but has already payed?

Tags: logo, client-relations

I've been working with a logo for a client whom has already payed a deposit. I created 3 different proposals until he picked one and started making changes from that chosen design.

In the next to last meeting we had, there were several issues with the chosen logo, I must say that the client's decisions were based under several comments from three members of his team. They decided that they just needed a "renovation" from the actual logo since they are more than attached to their logo, so, it is crucial that the new one maintains the **four** elements that are already captured in the old one.

Having that in mind I created a fourth proposal in which all four elements were polished and updated, and in our last meeting (yesterday) I emphasized the negative points from the previous meeting which led to this new proposal. The second the client checked out the logo, the comment was: "I don't like it."

I had really high expectations since the proposal captured everything that the client wanted and not wanted... Is it time to ask for a new deposit? even though the total price was already negotiated but I didn't consider to make all this changes.

Comment: What's I've done in the past is include a description of the work to be done in the contract, as well as a description of the time worked. I'll set a time limit on the project. Say "5 weeks or 50 hours (~10hrs per week)", which ever comes first after that the client is billed at an hourly rate. This helps keep them focused, and protects you from their wine parties.  I've scheduled calls with a client and for whatever reason after they received the initial sketches, the dragged their feet on providing feedback. I don't want a 1mo project to turn into 6mo unless they're paying for the time.

Comment: My favourite phrase for these situations is: "You understand there will be cost implications?"

Comment: I did not notice that this question have been already asked and answered... (newbie mistake) Anyway, thanks for your feedback guys :) I'm still learning how to stick to the base contract and still editing it regarding the hours spent in certain tasks. @elCavador I really appreciated your example. Thanks!